# How to determine which tests were run using JUnit Vintage vs. JUnit Jupiter

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

I'm trying to determine which unit tests are executed using JUnit 5 (Jupiter) and which tests are executed with JUnit 4 (Vintage)

I've already tried to see through IntelliJ, but it doesn't show.

Is there any plugin that shows this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such a plugin, but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist.

In any case, running your test "suite" via `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` should present a hierarchical view in your IDE with the engines as the top-level nodes. Though, Jupiter's dynamic tests will show up as "Unrooted Tests" (at least in Eclipse).

Another option is to execute the JUnit Platform Console Launcher using `tree` for the details mode. That will present a hierarchical view in the console with the engines as the top-level nodes.

Note, however, that neither of those approaches will provide a *test count* per test engine. If that's what you're specifically looking for, you'll want to implement your own `org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener`.

You'll find details on all of these options in the [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/).